# 1.99 dollar or 1.99 dollars?

Tags: differences, pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are these plural or singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/are-these-plural-or-singular)
>   [Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/should-we-use-plural-or-singular-for-a-fraction-of-a-mile)

I want to write price of some thing in my site.
As I know (maybe I am wrong) for things more than one we have to use "s". Related to 1.99 which is correct?
What is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: Do you mean pronunciation (how it is said), or orthography (how is it written)? I'm a bit confused as to why you need pronunciation here

Comment: Dear Simchona, Actually both I mean.

Comment: Also see  [Why “pay top dollar” and not “pay top dollars”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61525)

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63246/8019

Comment: ["The only number that is singular is one. All other numbers are plural"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/9796/300).